# Summing values in rows based on pairs of values in other columns in R

Tags: r, rows, plyr

I would like to sum up the values in column `Size` based on unique pairs of `Orig` and `Dest` where A-B does not equal B-A. Additionally, I would like these values to be summed for Month 1 and 2 which I want to call now "1" and then for 3 and 4 (which i want to call "2") cumulatively in a new column called "Semester". My real data is way more complicated than this example but working out this will help me work out the code for my data. Thanks a lot in advance.

The initial df would look following

```
Orig = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
Dest = c("B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A")
Month = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,1,2,4,4)
Size = c(30,20,10,10,20,20,30,50,20,60)
df <- data.frame(Orig,Dest,Month,Size)
df
   Orig Dest Month Size
1     A    B     1   30
2     B    A     2   20
3     A    B     3   10
4     B    A     4   10
5     A    B     2   20
6     B    A     3   20
7     A    B     1   30
8     B    A     2   50
9     A    B     4   20
10    B    A     4   60
```

And the desired outcome would look like this:

```
  Orig Dest Semester Size
1    A    B        1   80
2    B    A        1   70
3    A    B        2   30
4    B    A        2   90
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Semester=ifelse(Month%in%c(1,2),1,2)) %>% 
  group_by(Semester,Orig,Dest) %>% 
  summarise(Size=sum(Size))

  Semester Orig Dest Size
1        1    A    B   80
2        1    B    A   70
3        2    A    B   30
4        2    B    A   90
```

Though the column order is slightly different than yours. You could throw a `select` in there to re-order them.

Comment: I like `dplyr` because it can do some cool stuff fairly easily, but mostly because it's very readable for almost anyone. `data.table` can do these things with much less code and I recommend that as well if you don't know it.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! One more question: how to modify mutate function if I have 12 months and 3 trimesters (1,2,3,4=1, 5,6,7,8=2 and 9,10,11,12 = 3)

Comment: `ifelse(Month%in%c(1,2,3,4),1,ifelse(Month%in%c(5,6,7,8),2,3))`

Answer (score 3):

```
> require(data.table)
> dt1 <- data.table(df)
> setkey(dt1, Orig, Dest,Month) 
> df2 <- dt1[, list(Size=sum(Size)), by=list(Orig, Dest,Month)]
> df2
   Orig Dest Month Size
1:    A    B     1   60
2:    A    B     2   20
3:    A    B     3   10
4:    A    B     4   20
5:    B    A     2   70
6:    B    A     3   20
7:    B    A     4   70


> sapply(df2,class)
     Orig      Dest     Month      Size 
 "factor"  "factor" "numeric" "numeric" 

> library(plyr)
> df2$Month <- revalue(as.factor(df2$Month), c("1"="1", "2"="1","3"="2", "4"="2"))
> df2
   Orig Dest Month Size
1:    A    B     1   60
2:    A    B     1   20
3:    A    B     2   10
4:    A    B     2   20
5:    B    A     1   70
6:    B    A     2   20
7:    B    A     2   70
> df3 <- df2[, list(Size=sum(Size)), by=list(Orig, Dest,Month)]
> df3
   Orig Dest Month Size
1:    A    B     1   80
2:    A    B     2   30
3:    B    A     1   70
4:    B    A     2   90
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Semester:=(!Month %in% 1:2)+1L][,
        list(Size=sum(Size)) , .(Semester, Orig, Dest)]
#    Semester Orig Dest Size
#1:        1    A    B   80
#2:        1    B    A   70
#3:        2    A    B   30
#4:        2    B    A   90
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(Size~Orig+Dest +cbind( Semester=(!Month %in% 1:2)+1L), df, FUN=sum)
#   Orig Dest Semester Size
#1    B    A        1   70
#2    A    B        1   80
#3    B    A        2   90
#4    A    B        2   30
```

Answer (score 2):

here is another solution using `dplyr`

```
group_by(df, Orig, Dest, r = ntile(Month, n = 2)) %>%
+     summarise(sum(Size))
Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
Groups: Orig, Dest

  Orig Dest r sum(Size)
1    A    B 1        80
2    A    B 2        30
3    B    A 1        70
4    B    A 2        90
```